# Save file in previous Directory w/out knowing full folder path | Python

Tags: python-3.x, directory

Example:

```
filename = "foo"
contents = "bar"

with open('data/' + filename + '.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(contents, file)
```

However, this will create `data/` folder within the current working directory; `src/`.

How do I go back up a directory to then create this folder and save the file; without using full file path?

This Python script will run on any machine; so I cannot use full path.

Comment: `open('../data/' + filename + '.json', 'w')` ?

Comment: I'll try this now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `../` before your desired file path:

```
open('../data/' + filename + '.json', 'w')
```

Thanks, @MauriceMeyer